# Design Pattern to create multiple instances of a class without passing type

Tags: design-patterns, types, factory-pattern

I have a parent class and subclasses for specific types of DBDrivers. I want a way to create,  on demand multiple instances of a particular kind of DBDriver  without passing the type (String) to the class instantiating the instances. The kind/type will be mentioned in the properties file. Right now, I am reading the type of the driver from properties file, but I cannot decide on a pattern that will help me create the DBDriverFactory class at a higher level class and be able to create multiple instances at the lower/helper class without passing the type (String) of the driver to subclass.

Here is the pseudo code :

class Manager {

ClassA obj = new ClassA();

obj.initialize();

}

class ClassA{

```
// I want to have a factory class obj instantiated  in this ClassA
//which can be used create the instance in InnerClass run() method 


public void initialize(){

    for loop()
    {
        //create InnerClass thread and run 
    }
}


class InnerClass extends thread{

    public void run(){
        //create a instance of the Driverclass of driver type 'k'
        //something like factoryClass.createDriver(), should return a driver, 
        //without knowing the type of the driver.
    }
}
```

}

abstract class DriverClass{
    .......
}

SQLDriver extends DriverClass{
}

PostgresDriver extends DriverClass{
}

Comment: Show code you have now (at a high level; pseudocode OK). Explain what you don't like about it.

Comment: What about a simple factory http://corey.quickshiftconsulting.com/blog/first-post ?

Answer (score 0):

You only have two options:

- Either you pass the type as an argument to some class in the higher level. But you don't want that.
- Or the higher level class has knowledge of the concrete lower level classes. That violates the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Why don't you want to pass a parameter?

Comment: PS: with the abstract factory pattern, you can also pass the correct concrete factory to the higher level, but that only moves the problem. You would have a factory parameter in some class, instead of a type parameter in the factory.